# Download information in different sheets in Excel

Tags: java, excel, jsp

I have a requirement to download the data from DB to CSV/Excel. What I did is retrieving all the records from DB and store in the List and pass that list to the jsp page. In JSP page, I am using the below setting to download it to CSV/EXCEL.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");   
String fileName = "Report"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".xls";  
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment;filename="+fileName);
```

It was working fine. But I have an issues in it. Excel is capable of storing it only 65,536 rows. 
Even all the data getting downloaded to CSV/excel (> 65,536), while saving I am getting error from excel saying that it can't save more than 65,536 rows and the below data won't be saved.

```
This workbook contains data in cells outside of the row and column limit of the  selected file format.  
Data beyond 256 (IV) columns by 65,536 rows will not be saved.  
Formula references to data in this region will return a #REF! error.
```

I am not opt for POI apache third party at this point of time. 
Is it possible to download it in other sheets if it exceeds the max limit.

Example: Having data of around 100,000.

Download 65,536 - Sheet 1 
Remaining in Sheet 2,3.. of the same excel.

Any idea/input/suggestion on it?

Comment: I don't know how your class works, but the idea is that xls files are limited to 65536 rows but xlsx are unlimited. Did you try setting the content type to xlsx? That is: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Comment: If you MUST use csv, you can always create multiple csv files, put them in a zip file, and return the zip file to the user.

Comment: luanjot -  I tried as you said but when I open the file it shows that the file is not valid.
it says :
"either corrupted or the extension is not valid"
 
if the solution is to create a .xlsx file with an unlimited rows in a single sheet instead of .xls format with separated sheets,  it is ok for me but is not working :(  any idea?